# Mac Mail won't display message sent from Rails with inline attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer, email-attachments

Gmail display the mail message just fine. But Mac Mail won't render the email content. It will only display the inline attachment.

I'm using Rails 3.2.11 now.
Any one have successfully create email that contains inline attachment and work fine with Mac Mail? Please help.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it's a problem causing by premailer-rails3 gem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone would ever encounter this, I can confirm that by default Rails ActionMailer perfectly deliver email with inline attachments that works in Mac Mail. But some gem may interfere that. I experienced once with `premailer-rails3` (which I end up create my own fork, get rid of the interference).

Comment: Can you tell me what was the problem?